# Is it possible to create an SVN tag, preserving the timestamps of the source files?

Tags: svn

It seems that when using svn copy to create a tag, all files get the current timestamp.  I would like to have an exact duplicate including the timestamps of the original files.  Is this possible?

Comment: How did you create the tag? SVN tag supposed to be a symlink to target, so typically done on folder level..which should keep all files timestamp unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to turn on `use-commit-times` configuration. This is the snippet of that configuration from [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)

> use-commit-times
>
> Normally your working copy files have timestamps that reflect the last time they were touched by any process, whether your own editor or some svn subcommand. This is generally convenient for people developing software, because build systems often look at timestamps as a way of deciding which files need to be recompiled.
>
> In other situations, however, it's sometimes nice for the working copy files to have timestamps that reflect the last time they were changed in the repository. The svn export command always places these “last-commit timestamps” on trees that it produces. By setting this config variable to yes, the svn checkout, svn update, svn switch, and svn revert commands will also set last-commit timestamps on files that they touch.

Comment: thanks, I already knew about use-commit-times but it doesn't work for svn copy operations.  It does work for svn checkout, svn update, svn switch, and svn revert according to http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config.  I had thought that svn copy would copy all attributes of the files copied but it doesn't.  And anyway if you think about it, an svn copy IS a commit so the commit time would be the time added to the repo.  It turns out, though that I don't even need this functionality.

Comment: That is weird. As far as I know, _svn copy_ for folder in subversion is always cheap copy aka snapshot a hardlink to original folder. The files under the folder retain their metadata, which should include the  timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create a tag? Did you use `svn cp` on a working directory you've checked out somewhere, or did you use the URL form of the `svn copy` command? To create tags and branches, you should use the URL form:

```
$ svn cp --parents -r$rev \
    -m"Creating tag 4.10 for project from Revision $rev" \
    http://repo/svn/trunk/proj@$rev http://repo/svn/tags/4.10/proj
```

Note I use `-m` to set the commit message because the copy is done on the server and committed immediately. If I didn't include this, and `SVN_EDITOR` or `EDITOR` is set, you'll be asked for a commit message.

Note I also use `--parent` and I use `-r` and revision pinning (the `@$rev` on the end). This makes sure I tag the revision I want. The `--parents` will automatically create any parent directories if they are missing. It never hurts to have it.

No working directory is involved. Everything is done directly on the server. No physical files are copied over.

If you do it this way, the *timestamps* of the files in the tags are the same as what they were on the trunk or the branch. It will be the timestamp of their last commit. If you do `svn cp` on local files, the copied files will have the timestamp of when you did the copy. Not to mention that it takes much longer to do.